# what the need of using single and float keywords separately . when we have to use single in the real time scenario?

Tags: c#

when i am working with single and float in c#, i am getting the same result for both, then why 2 separate keywords.

```
namespace WpfApplication1 {
    /// /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml ///
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            // Console.WriteLine("correct1");
            float a = 10.6f; Single b = 10.6f;

            Console.WriteLine("correct"+(a/b));
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**float is an alias for single.**

[float C# - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx)

> (Remember that float is an alias for the System.Single type.)

Answer (score 3):

> what the need of using single and float keywords separately . when we have to use single in the real time scenario?

The two keywords are interchangable.

`float` is actually provided by the C# *language*, and is an alias for `System.Single`.  You can't use `Single` by itself, as its not merely a keyword, but the `System.Single` type.  This requires a `using System;` at the top of your file or fully qualifying it.  `float`, on the other hand, is a language provided keyword, and will work in any scenario, without bringing in the namespace.

This is also the case with `int`/`System.Int32`, `double`/`System.Double`, etc.

Comment: can we directly use single keyword instead of float

Comment: @sindhu You can use `Single` if you have `using System;`, since it's a type.  `float` will work without any `using` directives.