# What's the difference between Single.TryParse and float.TryParse in C#?

Tags: c#

What's the difference between Single.TryParse and float.TryParse in C#?

```
float a, b;
float.TryParse("0.01", out a);
Single.TryParse("0.02", out b);
```

Comment: none. they're the same. float is an alias for single

Comment: possible duplicate of [what the need of using single and float keywords separately . when we have to use single in the real time scenario?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779192/what-the-need-of-using-single-and-float-keywords-separately-when-we-have-to-us)

Answer (score 5):

It's the same method.

The only difference is that the `float` keyword is an alias for the `System.Single` type, so you can use it without having a `using System;` at the top of the file.

The exact equivalent would be:

```
global::System.Single.TryParse("0.02", out b);
```

as that would work exactly as the `float` version regardless what you have included or defined.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `float` in C# seems to be a throwback to its C/C++ heritage. `float` still maps to the `System.Single` type in C#, so the keyword just exists for convenience. You could just as well declare the variable as `Single`

Answer (score 0):

There is none. Single is the wrapper class for a float.